# Best index to cover a mix of exact match and less/greater than query in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have a table which I need to filter on (using sqlite), it has 3 fields in the query:

```
WHERE x <= 'something' AND y = 'something' AND z = 'SOMETHING ELSE'
ORDER BY x DESC
```

I was wondering what's the best index to cover this query.

I have tried a few, for example:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_x_y_z ON  user_messages(
    x, y, z
);

CREATE INDEX idx_y_z ON  user_messages(
    y, z
);
```

but the best I can get is:

```
SEARCH TABLE table USING INDEX idx_y_z
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

Is that optimal or I can avoid the `USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY`?

By reading https://explainextended.com/2009/04/01/choosing-index/ it seems that to be the case, but since the query is slightly different (we order by a field we filter on), I was wondering if maybe is not exactly the same.

Also, I am struggling to find good resources on this, a lot of it addresses the most common scenarios, while it's a bit harder to find more in depth resources, do you have any suggestion?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Turns out there was another issue, I have oversimplified the schema in the original question.

One of the fields had a type of `BOOLEAN`, and I was matching it by using the `IS FALSE` operator, which would return the right number of rows, while `= 0` would not for some reasons.

When querying with `=` it would not use a `TEMP B-TREE`, while it would when using `IS FALSE`.

To address this issue I have just created an index excluding the `BOOLEAN` field, and `B-TREE` was not used anymore, only `SEARCH-TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the query planner documentation](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html):

> Then the index might be used if the initial columns of the index (columns a, b, and so forth) appear in `WHERE` clause terms. The initial columns of the index must be used with the `=` or `IN` or `IS` operators. The right-most column that is used can employ inequalities.

So since your `WHERE` has two exact comparisons and one less than or equal, that one should come last in an index for best effect:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_y_z_x ON user_messages(y, z, x);
```

Using that index with a query with your `WHERE` terms:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM user_messages
   ...> WHERE x <= 'something' AND y = 'something' AND z = 'something'
   ...> ORDER BY x DESC;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH TABLE user_messages USING INDEX idx_y_z_x (y=? AND z=? AND x<?)
```

As you can see, it fully uses the index, with no temporary table needed for sorting the results.

More, essential, reading about how sqlite uses indexes can be found [here](https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html).

Comment: Also, [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com) is *the* guide to database indexing in general (Though not of all it applies to sqlite).

Comment: Thanks, turns out there was another issue, I have oversimplified the schema in the original question. 
One of the fields had a type of `BOOLEAN`, and I was matching it by using the `IS FALSE` operator, which would return the right number of rows, while `= 0` would not for some reasons.
When querying with `=` it would not use a `TEMP B-TREE`, while it would when using `IS FALSE`. 
To address this issue I have just created an index excluding the `BOOLEAN` field, and `B-TREE` was not used anymore, only `SEARCH-TABLE`.